# Switching Angular view not updating variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-view

I'm just building out a simple app to learn `AngularJS` and having trouble updating variables when switching views. Here's what I have so far:

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })

  .state('team', {
    url: '/team',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/team.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

Here's part of my controller:

```
function MainController($timeout, webDevTec, toastr, $resource, $scope) {
var vm = this;

var GetTeam = $resource('https://apisite.com/api_endpoint/:teamId', {teamId: '@id'});
vm.teamName = '';
function getTeamInfo(id) {
  var teamObj = GetTeam.get({teamId: id});
    $timeout(function(){
      vm.teamName = teamObj["name"];
    },100)        
};

vm.getTeamInfo = getTeamInfo;
}
```

Then in my main.html I call getTeamInfo with a ng-click:

```
 <ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="team in main.teams" ng-click="main.getTeamInfo(team.id)"><a href="#/team">{{ team.name }}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Clicking on that link will take you to team.html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3>{{ main.teamName }}</h3>
                <ul class="list-group">
                  . . . 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For some reason "`main.teamName`" is not updating. I've tried the `$scope.$apply(function(){vm.teamName = teamObj["name"]}` approach as well with no luck. I also did '`console.log(teamObj["name"])`' before `vm.teamName` and `'console.log(vm.teamName)'` after to see if I get the expected results and I do. I just have no idea now why it's not updating the new view.

Thank you for your insight, patience, and time!

**UPDATE 1**

I also tried using $scope on my variables ($scope.teamName) and using $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.teamName = teamObj["name"]}) with no luck.

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried called $scope.$apply(); after 'vm.teamName = teamObj["name"]' with no luck

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: why do you need to use $timeout?

Comment: user $scope with your variable name instead "this" (you have assigned it into vm).

Comment: @haillie it was a suggestion I read from other users that had a similar issue as me. My understanding is that $timeout can be used to trigger another $digest cycle to update the data-bindings.

Comment: try replacing `vm.getTeamInfo = getTeamInfo; ==>` to `$scope.getTeamInfo = getTeamInfo;`

Comment: @Pilot thank you for the suggestion. I gave it a try but it still didn't work.

Comment: To me it looks like your asych object does not gets resolved

Comment: @Pilot oh ok. I did not think of that. I just console.log(teamObj.$resolved) and it shows 'true.' Am I looking in the wrong area to check if it's resolved?

Comment: I think you should be using resolve inside your state. you just need to resolve all before you move on to next state..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83278/discussion-between-pilot-and-nam-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `teamObj` is not populated yet at the point when you assign `vm.teamName`

You would make your life so much easier if you just reference `teamObj` rather than creating a new property.

I made a plunker based on a modified version of your code to show a possible implementation. I couldn't get it to work using the **controllerAs** syntax and I'm not entirely sure why (possibly because of some issues related to sharing a controller; not sure). Anyway, hopefully it will be of some help to you.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/20SHlwIZF7UkeIqzfIL1?p=preview)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router', 'ngResource']);

app.controller('MainController', MainController);
app.config(routeConfig);

function MainController($timeout, $scope, $resource) {

  // mock data
  var GetTeam = $resource('http://demo7592070.mockable.io/teams/:teamId', {teamId: '@id'});
  //var GetTeam = $resource('https://apisite.com/api_endpoint/:teamId', {teamId: '@id'});

  $scope.teamName    = 'undefined';
  $scope.getTeamInfo = getTeamInfo;

  function getTeamInfo(id) {

    var teamObj = GetTeam.get({teamId: id});

    $scope.teamName = teamObj.name;
    $scope.teamObj = teamObj;

  };

}

function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'MainController'
  })

  .state('team', {
    url: '/team',
    templateUrl: 'team.html',
    controller: 'MainController'
  });

  console.log('ROUTECONFIG');

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

       <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <a ui-sref="home">home</a>
    <a ui-sref="team">team</a>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<h1>Home</h1>

<pre>$scope.teamName        => {{teamName}}</pre>
<pre>$scope.teamObj         => {{teamObj}}</pre>
<pre>$scope.teamObj.name    => {{teamObj.name}}</pre>

<button ng-click="getTeamInfo(1)">Get Team 1</button>
```

**team.html**

```
<h1>Team</h1>

<pre>$scope.teamName        => {{teamName}}</pre>
<pre>$scope.teamObj         => {{teamObj}}</pre>
<pre>$scope.teamObj.name    => {{teamObj.name}}</pre>

<button ng-click="getTeamInfo(2)">Get Team 2</button>
```